# HTML: Not downloading file on click

Tags: html

I wish to download excel file on click/trigger:

```
<a href="/download/test.xlsx" download>
   <button id = 'download' type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" onclick="">
       Download File
   </button>
</a>
```

This while clicking is failing as it is trying to go to `"file:///C:/download/test.xlsx"`.
What is wrong here?

Comment: Where should it go instead?

Comment: there is download folder in the same folder as this script. There is a test file inside that folder.

Comment: paste the whole path like `<a href="c:/user/hp/download/test.xlsx" download>`

Comment: @Tery Remove the `/` at the beginning, so it like `<a href="download/test.xlsx">`

Comment: @Progman it doesn't work!

Comment: @Tery Please [edit] your question to include a listing of the directories and files you have. Also add the current source code you have (with the removed `/` from the front).

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct except the file file path.

You need to have the **file** in the **same folder** in which you have **your html file**.
So if the files name is **some_text.txt** which is in the same folder, then use the following code:

```
    <a href="some_text.txt" download>
                            <button id = 'download' type="button" onclick="">
                                Download File
                            </button>
                        </a>
```

It worked for me, it will also work for you.
You could also try replacing it with images also.
For more check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp